# export graphic from javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, svg, ping, latency

I need to extract either the values or a high quality image of the latency graph from http://www.azurespeed.com.

I've been looking at how DOMs work and have somewhat isolated the ping values using Chrome console, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to extract them in a reasonable way, I'm looking to get a latency graph of the main locations US, EU, Brazil, China etc, at different times of the day and week. So I need something that can be replicated.

It's my first time asking something here and I'm afraid of being too broad, I looked at the script that is making these pings and ideally i'd like to document.write the values and do those graphs on excel but after going in circles for a few days I'm asking the masters for guidance.

Comment: You could run Chrome in [headless mode](https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a) or check out [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: I've come up with this $('#latency-table').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){console.log($('#latency-table tr:eq(1)').html());}); but have no idea how to extract the values out of the console